# Loading an bmp using ImageMagick

Tags: c++, imagemagick, bmp

I'l loading a bmp image using Image Magisk like this:

```
#include <Magick++.h> 
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std; 

int main(int argc,char **argv)
{ 
  Magick::InitializeMagick(*argv);

  Magick::Image image;
  try { 

    // Read a file into image object 
    image.read( argv[1] );

    cout << "image: " << argv[1] << endl; 
    cout << image.xResolution() << endl;
    cout << image.yResolution() << endl;

  } 
  catch( Magick::Exception &error_ ) 
    { 
      cout << "Caught exception: " << error_.what() << endl; 
      return 1; 
    } 
  return 0; 
}
```

The image I'm loading is this one:

[image: e]

Its a bmp and it can be loaded here [the Actual bmp](http://ge.tt/3SiPaDd/v/0?c), the code compiles fine, but the resolution information is wrong, the program outputs:

```
image: ../sd_nineteen/HSF_0/F0000_14/HSF_0_F0000_14_C0000_14_100_e_65.bmp
0
0
```

Whats going on, is there a problem with imagemagick or with my image(I'm guessing there is a problem with my image).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Martin, it appears as though some image types (eg TIFF) support view resolutions, which are different than the actual image dimensions.  The documentation on the topic is sparse, but looking at the source code it appears it may also have something to do with image density/DPI info.

Regardless of format, the actual image dimensions can be retrieved using the `columns()` and `rows()` methods of the Image class, rather than the `(x/y)Resolution()` methods.

Comment: HA! You are correct. That was the error. I've been looking for a javadoc style documentation for ImageMagick...

Comment: @MartinKristiansen -- here are the docs for Magick++:  http://www.imagemagick.org/Magick++/Documentation.html   Also, I've found their message board to be fairly helpful, in the future you may get a better response posting there as well:  http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/    Good luck!

Comment: however.. I still cant save the image... or in otherwords the image does when saved claim to bave dimensions of 0x0

Comment: @MartinKristiansen -- how are you trying to save the img?

Comment: `image.write( argv[2] );` I simply output the image that I have just loaded.. and I'm guessing that the header of the image disapears.

Comment: @MartinKristiansen - weird.  Does the built-in Imagemagick app `convert` handle the image properly?  eg, `convert.exe foo.bmp foo2.bmp` .  IM seems to introduce odd bugs here and there, depending on the version

Comment: Nope it does not.. the build in one does the exact same thing.

Comment: i looked at the image in a hex editor and decided to just pick the pixels by hand... Damn you Image Magick